# Django : Register or load { % block content % } tag in HTML

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to extend my templates .

base_layout.html:

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Articles</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "{% static 'styles.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

article_list.html:

```
{% extends 'base_layout.html' %}


{% block content %}
    <h1>Article List</h1>
    <div class = "articles">
        {% for article in articles %}
        <div class = "article">
            <h2><a href = "#">{{ article.title}}</a></h2>
            <p>{{ article.body }}</p>
            <p>{{ article.date }}</p>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

When i run this i am getting the error like this:

```
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 11: 'blockcontent'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

What mistake am i doing?

Comment: You have a typo _somewhere_ (it's not in the sections you have already posted): `blockcontent` instead of `block content`.

Comment: Rather than using ```{% load static from staticfiles %}```. Use ```{% load static %}```